# UIPageControl gets unselected

Tags: objective-c, ios, uipagecontrol

I have a problem with the UIPageControl which sometimes get in a stage where all dots are unselected.

I have a simple UIView with a UIScrollView and a UIPageControl. In the UIViewController i fetch the content for the scrollview from CoreData via the FetchedResultsController and its delegate methods.
Also I have a edit UIView with a UITableView from which I can add or delete elements shown in the scrollview.

If I in the edit view, remove all elements and add a few again and return to the main view, I see a scrollview with the right content, a pagecontrol with the right number of dots BUT none of the dots are marked as selected.

currentPage on the pagecontrol is set to 0 and numberOfPages is set to 4.

A dot is first selected when I start scrolling to the right due to my scrollview delegate methods.

Hope you can help me.

Cheers
Morten

Answer (score 3):

I have had a problem that may be the same as this one. The fix was to set the current page to the number of pages, then set it to its desired value. Something about changing the number of pages leaves it in a state where it does not update its appearance if the current page is subsequently set to 0.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to refresh the UIPageControl by using `[UIPageControl setNeedsDisplay];`?

Comment: Tried added [self.pageControl setNeedsDisplay]; in viewWillAppear, but it doesn't resolve the issue.

Comment: I will try to make an example project first thing next week.